# How to sort faster than n log n (given a strong condition on the list)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I was asked the following question (didn`t know at all the approach how to solve it)
Given an array *arr* of *n* `int`s we need to sort it.We already know that *k* of this `int`s are  placed in the original *arr* as in sorted array.(just don`t know which of them)
They told that such sorting is much better than `nlogn` - i have no any clue...
Any advices?

Comment: Do we know how large `k` is in comparison to `n`?

Comment: @Dukeling - no we dont

Comment: Probably be better to ask this on programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @kfsone It's just fine on [so].

Comment: @Yakov Are you sure? If `k` can be `0`, this is essentially asking to sort a completely unsorted array, in which case specifying that `k` of them are in the correct position is largely redundant (and in which case any non-comparison-based [sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) can probably be the right answer).

Comment: @Dukeling - yes I am.Probab;y the complexity should be a function of k i k==0 it will give nlogn

Comment: @Yakov, in C++ the range of integers is bounded by their size, typically 32 bits. So radix sort can work. If `int`s were unbounded as in Python it would be a different story.

Comment: @Dukeling I didn't vote to close, I just suspect he'll get more active/better answers over there.

Comment: @Yakov the k elements are consecutive? and the rest are misplaced? if not so I don't think there is much clue here :D

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question while it remains ambiguous. Was the interviewer any clearer—did they give an example?

In particular, when you say "k elements are placed in the original array as in the sorted array", do you mean mean 'in the exact same positions' (stronger) or 'in the same relative order' (weaker)? Also, are the k elements contiguous?

Comment: @ColonelPanic wait, so, is this question ambiguous, or not? It seems to be, but if it is, why didn't you vote to close? (by the way, http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3643249)

Comment: @JanDvorak Refinement and clarification is a natural and necessary stage of problem solving. People like to ask general questions, eg. "How are the prime numbers distributed?", "Is sexual reproduction better than asexual reproduction?", and "What kinds of data can be sorted faster than n log n?" too big to answer decisively. There are many insightful answers, but they refine to precise models, definitions and conditions (eg. "What's the limit of the quotient of the prime counting function and n/log n ?"). Unless you already know the answer—or are God—you have to ask the general question first.

Comment: Amusingly, Stack Overflow is fickle. If you take the care to word a question eloquently, define it precisely and give examples, it's likely to be closed "this looks like your homework". This has happened to me.

I think the system is biased because the ballot (which may take hours or days) allows only votes to 'close', and doesn't give the tolerant any opportunity to vote 'keep open'.

Comment: @colonel the criteria for closure are "can this question be answered in its current state?". The current (top-voted) answers appear to be guesswork.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

the key fact is that you're working with integers and you know the largest key, which is exactly when radix sort is used and its complexity is linear.

also second approach if k of them are already sorted you can use some version of shell sort with sequence that will yield the best result

Comment: As far as I know radix sort helps when we know the numbers range - here we do not.The elements of arr are integers (any) we just know that k of this elements are placed in the places where thay will remain after sorting also

Comment: I don't really see how shell-sort will help here - you'll just end up moving the already sorted elements around, and with the k-already-in-the-correct-position mention, radix sort clearly wasn't what was intended to be used.

Comment: sorry i missread i thought k was the largest key. for insetion sort this algorithm will probably run in O(n) for sufficiently large k, but the prob is k can be anything, ranging from 2 on so we dont get anything by insertions sort or any other partially sorted array specific for that matter. we have to know is k sufficiently large

Answer (score 5):

If we do not know:

1. how `k` and `n` are related to each other
2. and how exactly the `k` elements are located in the array

There is simple no option we can do much better than `Θ(nlog(n))` in the worst case.

Why:

1. Let put `k=1` and good luck...
2. Let say that `k=0.9n` and let place the k elements in the front. Even if we knew that they are in the front, then we still have to sort array of size `0.1n`, so in the worst case we need `0.1*n*log(0.1*n)=0.1*n*(log(0.1)+log(n))=0.01*nlog(n)-0.1*n` comparisions which is `Θ(n*log(n))`.

Of course this is just theoretical result for the worst case. In practice the information that there  are exactly `k` elements on proper places, can limit significantly amount of work to be done. But for sure we need to know bit more about `k` and `n` (or at least assume something).

Answer (score 4):

Selection sort is a good choice when your array is already mostly sorted; it should perform only `O(n(n-k)` swaps. If the sorted elements tend to be contiguous, then Timsort might also perform well. In neither case will you do better than `O(n log n)` for sufficiently small k, of course.

Comment: Why not quick sort?Evry time we choose the pivot we know that pivot will be placed as in sorted array...here we have already k such pivots.....Just looks like quick sort complexirty should be much better

Comment: In the worst case where the array is completely sorted, quicksort does not do well.

Comment: If you don't know which points are already sorted, they won't be of much help to you with quicksort (which will move them out of place during its recursive steps).

Comment: +1 because I think this might be what they were looking for (I stand to be corrected). But, if it was, and the question was stated as above, i.e. we don't know anything more about `k`, that's just wrong (i.e. bad interviewers, not bad answer) - it will still be, with the below improvement, `O(n log n)` in the worst case, and `O(n^2)` natively. **Improvement** - I'd probably just have added a calculation based on the values of `n` and `k` to dynamically switch between selection sort and something better when `k` is small.

Answer (score 1):

[Adaptive sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_sort) is a kind of sort algorithms which take advantage of existing order in its input. Insertion sort is one of the adaptive sorts, which works well when the array is almost sorted. Of course, the worst case is O(N^2).

There are other adaptive sort such as,
[Adaptive heap sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_heap_sort), which use [treap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap) to take the advantage of ordered elements when build the heap. [Adaptive merge sort(Natural merge sort)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort) and [Smoothsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothsort)

The theoretical complexity will also be O(N*lnN), but they might perform more effectively when the data is partly sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:

1. Locate the run of k contiguous elements already in order
2. Sort the other n-k elements
3. Merge the two sorted lists

Example with n=8, k=4.

> ['echo', 'cat', 'bat', 'board', 'hand', 'hotel', 'kilo', 'hit']

Locate the 4 contiguous elements already in order.

> ['echo', 'cat', **'bat', 'board', 'hand', 'hotel', 'kilo',** 'hit']

(As it happens, we found 5 already in order. All the better.)

Sort the other elements

> [cat, echo, hit]

Merge the two sorted lists

> ['bat', 'board', 'cat', 'echo', 'hand', 'hit', 'hotel', 'kilo']

Done.

The time complexities of the three steps are

1. O(n)
2. O((n-k)log(n-k))
3. O(n)

For any fixed the ratio k/n, the second step dominates (for large enough n).

Comment: "Locate the run of k elements already in order" - If I understand "a run" correctly, it's not that - they can be anywhere relative to each other (not necessarily next to each other). If I don't, how would you do this?

Comment: @Dukeling that's indeed a much weaker condition. I doubt much/any optimisation would be possible.

Comment: @Dukeling In fact, your suggested condition may be so weak to be true of *every* sequence (that's long enough). See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/616027/6450